# Find infimum of this set

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum

I need to find infimum of this set

$$ \left\{ \frac a {b+c} + \frac b {a+c} + \frac c {a+b} : a,b,c \in \mathbb R^+\right\}$$

Some hint would be helpful

Comment: Here we use LaTex for mathematical formulas.

Comment: @sinbadh : No, we don't.  We use MathJax. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^+$, $n\in\mathbb Z^+$:

$$\frac{a}{b+nc}+\frac{b}{c+na}+\frac{c}{a+nb}\ge \frac{3}{n+1}$$

I've posted a proof before [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607341/prove-that-if-a-b-and-c-are-positive-real-numbers-then-fraca3a32b/1607350#1607350):

First, notice that $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$ for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$, because this is equivalent to $\frac{1}{2}\left((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\right)\ge 0$, which is true (or by the [Rearrangement Inequality](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Rearrangement_Inequality)).

Also by the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:

$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a}{b+nc}\ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum_{\text{cyc}}a(b+nc)}=\frac{\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^2+2\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab}{(n+1)\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab}$$

$$\ge \frac{\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab+2\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab}{(n+1)\sum_{\text{cyc}}ab}=\frac{3}{n+1}$$

$n=1$ gives [Nesbitt's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality), which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done directly by [Nesbitt's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality)

Comment: You are a $3$k reputation user, so,you should know that link only answers  are not a good policy here.

Comment: Nesbitt say us that infimum is $3/2$. The link i put has several proofs of this fact.

Comment: Here every knows this, this is a well known inequality. But, Only link-based answers turns out useless, when the link becomes extinct. It is not too big to demonstrate that result here. And often we have to *recommend deletion* of such link only answers, when flagged as *low-quality post*.